# unknown provider after minify angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have created angular app and I want to deploy it in production I have minified whole angular app using gulp-uglyfy after minify whole app I got error of unknown provider for authInterceptor here is my authInterceptor

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('competitiveMain', [
    "ui.router",
    "ui.bootstrap",
    "oc.lazyLoad",
    "ngSanitize",
    "ngCookies",
    "pascalprecht.translate",
    "ngStorage",
    "timer",
    "competitiveAdmin",
    "smart-table",
    "toastr"
]).factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
    return {
        // Add authorization token to headers
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($cookieStore.get('user')) {
                config.headers.Authorization = $cookieStore.get('user').token;
            }
            return config;
        },

        // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
        responseError: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                $location.path('/');
                // remove any stale tokens
                $cookieStore.remove('user');
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
            else {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        }
    };
})
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
        //Http Interceptor to check auth failures for xhr requests
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
    }]);
```

})();

Can someone suggest me why this happening after minifying js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common issue, always make sure when you pass dependencies that you include the dependency names as **`strings`** so that Angular will know what to inject after minification

Change your factory code as follows,

```
.factory('authInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q','$cookieStore','$location', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to AngularJS style guide and there is an explanation why it's happening.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection

So change your factory to:

```
.factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor);

authInterceptor.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$q", "$cookieStore", "$location"];

function authInterceptor($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location)
{
    ...
}
```